# Alternate ListBox row colors

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I'm trying to stylish this ListBox with alternate row colors:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" Background="{x:Null}" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged" >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <local:AltBackgroundConverter x:Name="AltBackgroundConverter" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0" Height="50" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AltBackgroundConverter}}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Titulo}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"  />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This is the `AltBackgroundConverter.cs`:

```
public class AltBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (!(value is int)) return null;
            int index = (int)value;

            if (index % 2 == 0)
                return Colors.White;
            else
                return Colors.Gray;
        }

        // No need to implement converting back on a one-way binding
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Obviously, it's not working because I'm not achieving how to bind the row number to the converter. As you can see, I'm binding a entire ListBox Item.

[image]

I think the solution should be really simple, but I can't find it.

Comment: You aren't binding a property in your Background attribute. Try setting the binding Path to the property you want value to be in the converter. Or consider this approach http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1780-alternate-row-color-listbox-wpf.aspx.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know which property to value, since I can't find a way to bind row's number. Additionally, triggers aren't supported in WinRT apps. So, this approach doesn't work. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your solution right now.

1. Your binding to your list items, while the converter needs an integer to figure out if an item is even or odd. Based on your screenshot you should change it so it looks like this:

   Background="{Binding Numero, Converter={StaticResource AltBackgroundConverter}}"
2. Your converter returns a color, while the `Background` is a brush, so you could fix it like this:

   ```
   public class AltBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
   {
       private Brush whiteBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
       private Brush grayBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);

       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
       {
           if (!(value is int)) return null;
           int index = (int)value;

           if (index % 2 == 0)
               return whiteBrush;
           else
               return grayBrush;
       }

       // No need to implement converting back on a one-way binding
       public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Things should start working at this point, but your highlighting will only highlight the text instead of entire rows. This is how you can fix that up:

   ```
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style
           TargetType="ListBoxItem">
           <Setter
               Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
               Value="Stretch"></Setter>
       </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   ```